# What is the difference between $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] and $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']?

Tags: php, apache

What’s the difference between `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` and `$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']`? How do I use them?

When I run `print_r($_SERVER)`, `PATH_INFO` and `ORIG_PATH_INFO` are not present in the array. Why not? How can I enable them?

I have read the PHP manual on them, but still don’t understand them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `PATH_INFO` variable is only present if you invoke a PHP script like this:

```
http://www.example.com/phpinfo.php/HELLO_THERE
```

It's only the `/HELLO_THERE` part after the `.php` script. If you don't invoke the URL like that, there won't be a `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` environment variable.

The `PORIG_` prefix is somewhat uncommon. `PATH_INFO` is a standard CGI-environment variable, and should never be prefixed. Where did you read that? (There were some issues around PHP3/PHP4 if you invoked the PHP interpreter via cgi-bin/ - but hardly anyone has such setups today.)

For reference: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875

Comment: I think it's meant to be `ORIG_PATH_INFO`. It seems some server configurations create this instead of `PATH_INFO`.

Comment: Then it's pretty certainly a CGI handler setup. PHP would use the PATH_INFO over SCRIPT_FILENAME in some settings, so the server is likely configured to use an alternative name for path_info.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php: `ORIG_PATH_INFO`:
> Original version of 'PATH_INFO' before processed by PHP.

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
$path_info = !empty($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : (!empty($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] : '');
```

Answer (score 2):

PATH_INFO and ORIG_PATH_INFO are rarely used. These refer to anything in the request path (the part of the URL from the first / on) that comes after the name of the file, and the query string. Generally, you won't have a PATH_INFO in a URL.

I am guessing you mean ORIG_PATH_INFO and not PORIG_PATH_INFO. The path info may be manipulated by things like mod_rewrite and PHP scripts themselves. ORIG_PATH_INFO is the PATH_INFO as it was in the original request, before any rewriting or other manipulation was done to the string.

Comment: `PATH_INFO` is used in both Symfony and ZF so I wouldn't call it "rarely used"

Comment: Just to add to this as I needed to use `PATH_INFO` and got a bit misled by `PATH_INFO` apparently not being used that much. Based on WordPress using this internally: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.4.4/wp-includes/class-wp.php#L155. It's fair to say it's used [an awful lot](http://www.opensourcecms.com/general/cms-marketshare.php) so use it if you need to!

Comment: "...that comes after the name of the file, and the query string." - Note that PATH_INFO comes _before_ the query string, not after it.

Comment: `ORIG_PATH_INFO` is also used in Agavi (AgaviWebRequest.class.php).

Answer (score 2):

Prior to 5.2.4, `PATH_INFO` was apparently broken (not set) in the default configuration. Perhaps that's it.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31892

The PHP manual says that `ORIG_PATH_INFO` is:

> Original version of 'PATH_INFO' before processed by PHP.

Reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php