# $_SERVER[] doesn't return current url in browser on localhost

Tags: php

Following returns empty array, so on my localhost $_SERVER[] doesn't return anything. Why?

Url in browser looks like this: localhost/final/events/2012-10/

```
$current_url_all = parse_url($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
print_r($current_url_all);
```

What am I doing wrong? How else can I grab that last date piece from url?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629683/serverpath-info-and-serverporig-path-info-in-php

Comment: @jtheman It doesn't say what to use instead :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` instad, `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` seems to be just aviable if you invoke the script like a directory:

```
http://example.org/script.php/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Answer (score 0):

u can manipulate the string. use strpos to get the position of localhost/final/events/ then substring to get the rest.

also u can use `$end = end((explode('/', $url)));`

then get the last value from the array